# TTS Voices for Windows7 64 bits

Tags: c#, windows-7, text-to-speech, windows-7-x64

I'm currently looking for TTS Voices for win7 64bits.
I have troubles with Microsoft voices. I installed MS Hortense Fr-fr. I switch folders in regedit for put that one in wowsys64 folder.
And when I try to change voice in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech\SpeechUX\sapi.cpl I can't test voice cause bad installed or I just don't know why.
I think it's because MS voices are produced for win x86 and not win x64.
I'm looking for voices En-en and Fr-fr for win7 x64.
Anyone can help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with one of these: http://biblprog.com/en/speech_api/voices_sapi/

I also have Win7 x64, and I have tested SAPI speakers for Serbian, Croatian and Hebrew, so it is definitely possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I used **[TTS Ivona](http://www.ivona.com/us/for-individuals/voices-for-windows/)**. I have a Windows 7 @ 64bit OS. I used the english voices but I remember them having other languages as well.

They have a 30 day trial version. I was quite satisfied.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use IVONA to for my personal use and it works fine but IVONA is a private socity and it cost 480$ for use one voice (only one) for professionnal use....
I search everywhere solution for installing other voices than Anna (the default one) but without any success. But when I see IVONA, I'm sure it's possible.
I search a TTS specialist ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out

use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech\SpeechUX\sapi.cpl to configure your voice

Then add the sapi.dll to your project as a reference

```
resolve SpVoice 

C# code

SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
voice.Speak("Hello how are you");
```